# Why not keep the database online?

Tags: database

When you install this bitcoin thingy it takes like 6 GB of space from your computer. That's huge.

Why isn't there some kind of open source site that stores this info, and the client can access there when it needs to?

Comment: Bitcoin-qt is a "full client" which means that it need to keep all/most of the blockchain on disk. But you can also use a "light client" (SPV/web) like http://electrum.org/ or use a website like https://blockchain.info/wallet . I believe you can find download links to the blockchain on bitcointalk.org, but you still need to 'verify' it.